# Rotate the ticklabels while keeping the letter horizontal

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

When I use `ax.set_xticklabels(['somethinghere']*10, rotation='-90')`, I get a result like this:

[image: rotated word]

I want to just rotate the words while keeping the letters horizontal. What I expected is something like this:

[image: word going down]

How can I get a x axis label with the word going down instead of a rotated word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best way but certainly works

```
ax.set_xticklabels((['s\n''o\n''m\n''e\n''t\n''h\n''i\n''n\n''g\n' ])*10)
```

Comment: That's pretty simple and effective.